# Preserve newline while writing data from DB to file

Tags: java, jsp, textarea, line-breaks

I have a JSP page with a text-area when user clicks save button, it saves the data from the text area to the database. DB field corresponding to data from text-area is Clob . I need to write this data to a file (after converting clob to String), by preserving newline. But when I convert Clob to String, the newlines are missing

Can I preserve newline while converting clob data to String.

Comment: Please be more precise. You are referring to JSP. Is the text output inside of a JSP file? Then you have to insert `<br>` tags for line breaks.

Comment: Please, post the code which do insertion into DB

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that you want to output your text on a JSP page. Therefore, you have to convert it to HTML.

Replace all new line characters with [`<br>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp).

```java
String html = text.replace("\n", "<br>\n");
```

Additionally, you should escape the special characters in your text to HTML entities. Use [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml4()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) from the Commons-Lang library.